# Merge two project with GIT

Tags: git, merge, projects

I have multiple projects that (Dynamics CRM solutions for those who knows) that have have the same folder structure and I need to merge one project with another in order to:

- Merge files that have the same name.
- Add files from one project to the other if not exists.

What would be the best way doing it with GIT ?

- I have tried to create a single repository where I've uploaded project A. Then, I've created a branch from it where I've placed the project B. When I merge the branch project B into the branch project A, files from project A with the same name of project B are replaced by those from project B.
- I have also tried the submodules concept but it isn't finally the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the history and the fact that they were merged, then:

```
git clone git@projecta
cd projecta
git remote add -f projectb git@projectb
git merge projectb/master
```

If you don't care about history - then just place files manually and commit. It's possible to make a merge commit (that points to 2 parents) even in case of manual merge with low-level commands like `git-commit-tree`.

Comment: Thanks ! So it's two different GIT repositories and not branches ?

Comment: Git doesn't care if it's 2 repos or 2 branches or no branches at all. Git works with graphs of commits; branches & remote branches are just pointers to those commits. For Git origin/master & projectb/master are 2 pointers of the same kind. You can explore the content of `.git/refs/remotes` to find them.